# List object checking two properties

Tags: c#, list

In my code sample there are four patients father,Son, Grandson and Mother but only one is selected. In the lookup table father is linked to Son and son is linked to Grandson.  Now it need to check both patientid and childid because Grandson is in childid it will return isvalid false. All three father,Son and Grandson will need to be selected. Also because Mother is not in the lookup table it should also return Mother isvalid true. I am stuck where I selectedLookup table do I need to loop again the checking the selectedLookup? This is returning true but should return false because father and Son are not selected

use case 1 Mother is Selected and because there is no values for Mother in the lookup table is should return IsValid true This is working

use case 2 father,Son, Grandson all relation are selected this also should return return IsValid true this is working

use case 3 father,Son are selected this is missing Grandson so it should return IsValid false this is not working its returning true

use case 4 Grandson is only one selected but because it is relate to Son it should return false this is not working its returning true

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean IsValid = true;
        List<Patient> Patients = new List<Patient>();


        Patients.Add(new Patient() { id = 1, Name = "father", IsSelected = false });
        Patients.Add(new Patient() { id = 2, Name = "Son", IsSelected = false });
        Patients.Add(new Patient() { id = 3, Name = "Grandson", IsSelected =true });
        Patients.Add(new Patient() { id = 4, Name = "Mother", IsSelected = false });

        List<Lookup> Lookup = new List<Lookup>();

        Lookup.Add(new Lookup() { id = 1, patientid=1, childid=2 });
        Lookup.Add(new Lookup() { id = 2, patientid = 2, childid = 3 });


     var selectedPatients= Patients.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
      
    foreach (var Patient in selectedPatientsSelected)
    {
        var selectedLookup = Lookup.Where(y => y.childid == Patient.id || y.patientid == Patient.id).ToList();
        foreach (var relation in selectedLookup)
        {
            var related = relation;
            if (selectedLookup.All(t => t.patientid != related.id))
            {
                IsValid = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Process relation {0}", IsValid);
            }

        }
    }
        Console.WriteLine("Process relation {0}", IsValid);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Patient
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

class Lookup
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int patientid { get; set; }
    public int childid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're trying to achieve. You have entities (patients) and a lookup that indicates relation between entities (parent <---> child). Is the rule that if any patient has `IsSelected = true` then all linked patients (either directly or indirectly) should also have `IsSelected = true` and all not connected patients should have `IsSelected = false` then only if this is the case should it return `true` for `IsValid` and `false` otherwise?

Comment: Your class Patient needs another property for child either a class like : public List<Patient> children { get;set;} or a list of ids : public List<int> childrenIds { get;set;}

Comment: @Knoop I add some use case to help explain it should check if its a parent <---> child or child<---> parent and if its one of them are they also included in the Selection. if they are not include in the Selection then return `IsSelected = false` but if they are included return `IsSelected = true`

Comment: @jdweng can I use the Lookup childid object?

Comment: Yes if the parent is linked to the child.  A parent could have more than one child (I made a List) so then the check would use ANY since each child would have a different id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're saying is that every pair of `Patient` in your `Lookup` should have the same `IsSelected` value. This we can easily check. I convert the `patients` list to a `Dictionary<int, Patient>` so we can efficiently lookup a `Patient` by his/her `Id`. After that all we have to is check if all `lookup` entries fulfill the condition:

```
var patients = new List<Patient> {
    new Patient { id = 1, Name = "father", IsSelected = false },
    new Patient { id = 2, Name = "Son", IsSelected = true },
    new Patient { id = 3, Name = "Grandson", IsSelected = false },
    new Patient { id = 4, Name = "Mother", IsSelected = true }
};

var lookup = new List<Lookup>
{
    new Lookup { id = 1, patientid=1, childid=2 },
    new Lookup { id = 2, patientid = 2, childid = 3 }
};

var patientDictionary = patients.ToDictionary(p => p.id);

var IsValid = lookup.All(l => patientDictionary[l.patientid].IsSelected == patientDictionary[l.childid].IsSelected);
```

And we're done. Keep in mind though that there might be some border cases you missed (for example it might not be valid if no patient is selected), but this satisfies all cases you mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Apparently you don't actually have a list of patients with an `IsSelected` property, but you have a list of all the patients that are selected. This can also be used but then instead of using a `Dictionary` we can just use a `HashSet` containing the id's of all selected patients:

```
var patients = new List<Patient> {
    new Patient { id = 1, Name = "father", IsSelected = false },
    new Patient { id = 2, Name = "Son", IsSelected = false },
    new Patient { id = 3, Name = "Grandson", IsSelected = false },
    new Patient { id = 4, Name = "Mother", IsSelected = true }
};

var lookup = new List<Lookup>
{
    new Lookup { id = 1, patientid=1, childid=2 },
    new Lookup { id = 2, patientid = 2, childid = 3 }
};

var selectedPatients = patients.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();

var selectedPatientsHashSet = selectedPatients.Select(p => p.id).ToHashSet();

var IsValid = lookup.All(l => selectedPatientsHashSet.Contains(l.patientid) == selectedPatientsHashSet.Contains(l.childid));
```

For every relation we have they either both need to be contained in the `HashSet` (So they're both selected) or they both should not be contained in the `HashSet` (not selected).

Comment: I dont need to loop all the records?

Comment: Not from what you've told so far. In the example's you've given only the relations are relevant. But best way to test is try it out yourself. Copy this code in and change the `IsSelected` values around and see if all your use cases give the correct result

Comment: @Jefferson It's literally copied from the code you provided. It's your responsibility to provide a clear and full question. And I don't understand what you mean with "not in the object can I the Id?"

Comment: sorry IsSelected  is not in the object for Patient can I do something like this `patientDictionary[l.patientid] == patientDictionary[l.childid]`

Comment: I was just using it to test the different use case

Comment: @Jefferson No you can't do that. Your requirement is that the `IsSelected` value is the same for all connected patients, you can't determine that without access to `IsSelected`.

Comment: I can't use the selectedPatients ?

Comment: @Jefferson It was unclear from your question that it was needed to use the `selectedPatients` list, I've edited my answer to also provide code to use that list instead of checking the `IsSelected` property of your `patients` list.